# How do I prove that counting measure is subadditive?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

How do I prove that counting measure is subadditive?

Particularly, I'm confused about, what cases do I need to explore?

$$\mu^* \bigg(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i \bigg)$$

then since each $E_i$ is either some finite natural number or $\infty$, then do I need to induct or something?

Or perhaps one considers:

- all $E_i$ are finite
- at least one $E_i$ is infinite

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Not exactly since that proof proves additivity, not subadditivity.

Comment: @mavavilj I wonder though if the cases given there are the cases that I would explore as well.

Comment: The answer to that question contains the answer to your question.

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos How are additivity and subadditivity same though?

Comment: They aren't! The person who asked di other question used the wrong expression.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos What do you mean?

Comment: Read the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/848476/446262)!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $\sigma$-additivity is countable addivity, whereas I try to prove subadditivity.

Comment: I have nothing more to say about this.